# Automate CSV Import Into Outlook Calendar

Tags: python, powershell, csv, import, outlook

A CSV file will be created daily with the following fields: Subject, Description, Start Date and Start Time. I need automate the importing of this CSV file into a Outlook Calendar file.

One off imports into Outlook are very easy using the built in import function, but I havn't been able to find a way to automate this.

I think this would be easiest to do using a desktop Outlook, but am not opposed to importing it directly into Office 365.

I would prefer to do this with powershell or python as that's what I have experience in, but am open to different options as well.

*The O365 API seems overkill for my use case and I have limited experience with Javascript, but if it is my only option I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly with `requests` and this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations)?